# for loop in a single statement with list append function

Tags: python, list, for-loop

When i execute the below code,  i get the right results:

```
for i in quorum:
    lst.append(i.strip('l'))
 print lst

 op:
    ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

but when i try to have the for loop along with list append function in single line, i don't get the expected output (i.e the list elements as above).

what am i missing ? and why does it behave that way ?

```
lst.append(i.strip('l') for i in quorum)
print lst

op:
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x2996cd0>]
```

Comment: if argument is iterable and you want to add all elements from said iterable, you are looking for `list.extend` method. `list.append` adds argument to list, in your case iterable (generator expression) itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression in parens is a **generator expression (genex)**. It is an iterable, but `list.append()` doesn't iterate. Fortunately `list.extend()` does:

```
lst.extend(i.strip('l') for i in quorum)
```